# How to: XSL template that creates input hidden with dynamically ID

Tags: javascript, xslt, dom

I have this XML:

```
<EditRemote>
   <RemoteVendorServer>
      <FriendlyName><![CDATA[blabla]]></FriendlyName>
      <Description></Description>
      <CommunicationMethod>
         <GetExecutors>
            <Executor queryString=".*"/>
            <Executor queryString="[CX].*"/>
            <Executor queryString="[^CX].*"/>
         </GetExecutors>
         <RemoteAccess/>
      </CommunicationMethod>
   </RemoteVendorServer>
</EditRemote>
```

I would like to do applay-templates on "Executor" tags and to collect all queryStrings value into dynamically created hidden inputs with dynamical ID's. So my code shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     .
     .
    var queryCounter = 0;
    var c_UNDERSCORE_QUERY_STRING = "_queryString";
     .
</script>
     .
     .
<xsl:apply-templates select="EditRemote/RemoteVendorServer/CommunicationMethod/GetExecutors/Executor" mode="tcp"/>
 .
 .
 // at the bottom of the xsl file I create the template:
 <xsl:template match="Executor" mode="tcp">     
    <input value="{@queryString}">
         <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                queryCounter + c_UNDERSCORE_QUERY_STRING+"tcp";
            </script>
         </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                queryCounter + c_UNDERSCORE_QUERY_STRING+"tcp";
            </script>
         </xsl:attribute>
    </input>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        queryCounter++;
    </script>
</xsl:template>
```

What I got back to server is only the last query without the key name. It is somehow got into a different input called Description(textarea element) which is written in the xsl before the apply-templates above:
Server input: ...,Description=[^CX].*,...
I even see it in my UI that the query is inside the Description textarea when the page is loaded. What seems to be the problem in my code?

Comment: To be more precise the return value is: [^CX].*} I thisnk it got something to do with the value assigment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put script tags into `<xsl:attribute>`.

And you *definitely* cannot execute or access JavaScript from within XSLT - why do you think that this would be possible?

Try something like this.

```
<xsl:template match="Executor" mode="tcp">   
    <input value="{@queryString}" id="{position()}_queryString_tcp" name="{position()}_queryString_tcp" />
</xsl:template>
```

Read about

- [attribute value templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)
- the [`position()` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-position)

Comment: @shlomikl Even with XSLT there is something like "thinking too complicated". ;)